# Display highscores underneath each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a simple game in Python using Tkinter and manages to save/load highscores by writing them to a txt file with pickle. Now I want to display these highscores in a Toplevel window. The text file contains a single list that looks like this:

```
[('jonas2', 10.690415143966675), ('jonas', 8.847283124923706)]
```

The list gets ordered and the 10 highest scores are retrieved, that's all taken care of. Now I'm just struggling with displaying the list on the screen. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter? What part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: I've tried print("/n".join(high_scores)) but that gave me an error..

Answer (score -1):

you can read your file and `exec` it. for example:

```
line = f.readline()
exec("names=%s" % line)
```

now you can access to the list through `names` variable